# VBA: DateAdd and EoMonth stop working correctly in the middle of a loop

Tags: vba, excel, dateadd

So what I am trying to do is start with a date in one cell and then each row beneath it have it show a date that is one month later. So in row 3 of column 1, I have 1919 - Mar, so I want row 4 of column 1 to be 1919 - Apr, and so on. I've wrote a code to do this:

```
Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(3, 1) = MinDate
Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(3, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
For i = 1 To TotalMonths
    Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(3 + i, 1) = DateAdd("m", 1, Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(2 + i, 1))
    Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(3 + i, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
Next i
```

Where MinDate is a previously determined date and TotalMonths is a previously determined integer. When I do this, it works as I imagine it would work for a while, but on line 835, it starts messing up. This is how it appears:
1988 - May
1988 - Jun
1900 - Jan
1900 - Jan

And then it keeps repeating with January for a while, then sometimes it shows 1900 - Feb or 1900 - Mar, but the weird thing is, the very last line will show 2015 - Jul, which doesn't make sense, because the previous row's cell is 1900 - Mar. I have the same problem even when I try using EoMonth.

In a separate worksheet, I've tried the following code and it has worked perfectly throughout its entirety:

```
Dim z As Date
z = "01/11/1905"
Worksheets(4).Cells(1, 1) = z
Worksheets(4).Cells(1, 2) = z
Worksheets(4).Cells(1, 3) = z
For i = 1 To 60000
    Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + i, 1) = DateAdd("m", 1, Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 1))
    Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Worksheets(4).Cells(i, 2), 1)
    Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + i, 3) = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Worksheets(4).Cells(1, 3), i)
    Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + i, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
    Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + i, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
    Worksheets(4).Cells(1 + i, 3).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
Next i
```

All three columns have the same output and its exactly as I want it to appear. But if I try those three general methods in the context of my previous code, I run into the problem of it not working when it reaches 1988 - Jun. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any conditional formatting, or VBA events attached to the problematic worksheet? Can you upload a sample where we could reproduce the issue?

Comment: I did not. I actually figured out what was going wrong; there was a later section in my code that was affecting the dates column (and I didn't want it to; I just had a problem with an indexing that I fixed). Thank you for taking your time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself; it was a dumb mistake on my part. A later section in my code was affecting part of the dates column, which I guess led to the dates getting messed up, so I fixed the indexing of the code so it affected the the part of the spreadsheet that I had actually intended it to affect.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example with 1000 months and it worked:
1988 - Jan
1988 - Feb
1988 - Mar
1988 - Apr
1988 - May
1988 - Jun
1988 - Jul
1988 - Aug
1988 - Sep
1988 - Oct
1988 - Nov
1988 - Dec

Have you tried using DateSerial?

```
Sub test()

    Dim MinDate As Date
    Dim TotalMonths As Long
    Dim i As Long

    MinDate = DateSerial(1919, 1, 1)
    TotalMonths = 1000

    Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(3, 1) = MinDate
    Worksheets("FormattedData").Cells(3, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
    For i = 1 To TotalMonths
        With Worksheets("FormattedData")
            .Cells(3 + i, 1) = DateSerial(Year(.Cells(3 + i - 1, 1)), Month(.Cells(3 + i - 1, 1)) + 1, 1)
            .Cells(3 + i, 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy - mmm"
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```